# Error Occur while i'm using Android Studio “Type parameter bound for C in”

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, arraylist, kotlin

Error Type parameter bound for C in inline fun Iterable.mapTo(destination:C,transform:(T)-R):C is not satisfied : inferred type ArrayList is not a subtype of MutableCollection

Code is

```
private fun asContributor(): Func1<DataSnapshot, FireContributor> {
return Func1 { dataSnapshot ->
    val contributor = dataSnapshot.getValue(FireContributor::class.java)
    contributor?.setId(dataSnapshot.key)
    Log.d(TAG, "Contributor:" + contributor?.name + ", " + contributor?.avatar)
    val keys = ArrayList<String>()
    if (dataSnapshot.child(FireContributor.ROLES_SECTION).hasChildren()) {
        val children = dataSnapshot.child(FireContributor.ROLES_SECTION).children
        children.mapTo(keys) { it.key }
    }
    contributor?.roleIds = keys
    contributor
}
```

[image of error code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cJSA.jpg)

[another image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wad00.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create mutable list:

```
val keys: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
```

or

```
val keys = mutableListOf<String>()
```

Comment: if use this """""val keys: MutableList<String> = ArrayList() """" or ''''''''val keys = mutableListOf<String>()""""""" then Error Occure Type parameter bound for C in inline fun Iterable.mapTo(destination:C,transform:(T)-R):C is not satisfied : inferred type MutableList<String> is not a subtype of MutableCollection